# Chinese input in Linux Mint 13

Tags: x11, linux-mint, locale, input-method, mate-desktop

I started to use Linux Mint 13 MATE a few days ago. What frustrates me most is that I can't found anywhere to change my input language. In Windows, it is easy, just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. How can I configure the input and switch between them? Specifically I need a Chinese Traditional Input - Quick.

Comment: @Gilles Why did you delete the content about the input option? I provided it so that IF someone knows there ain't no Chinese Traditional - Quick input in Linux, he/she would tell me so.

Comment: I made a typo that caused the end of the question to be invisible, sorry. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

*System Tools ⇒ System Settings ⇒ Language Support ⇒ Install / Remove Languages*

Answer (score 1):

Check out about `ibus-setup`, shortcut of `Enable or disable`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps involved, as ibus and ibus-pinyin are not installed by default.

1. Install Chinese Language support via "Language Support" in the Control Center
2. Install the *ibus* and *ibus-pinyin* packages (using Synaptic or apt)
3. Reopen "Language Support" and change keyboard input to ibus
4. Run System Tools > ibus and select either pinyin or bopomofo as your input method
5. I had to restart at this point
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is the default shortcut to activate *ibus* input